# How to change models without losing data in production in Entity Framework 6 Code-First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code-First and my application is in production. I have to perform some changes in my models without lose any data.

I have to perform changes like these:

- Change a relationship of two entities, from **one-to-many** to **many-to-many**.
- Change an entity property's data type.

I need something like the Seed Database, but I need to load the data before change the model to later insert it again... I need to move the data. When I change the relationship I don't lose the data but the relation do.

How can I do this process?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You can try to create a EF migration from old model to new and then apply it to your db. Your first change a relationship will migrate fine but I am not sure that the second change will migrate fine. You can check generated migration' code or apply migration to temporary db.

Comment: Querying the old model in the Seed Database?

Comment: EF migration migrate your data from old model to new. It's mean that EF try to "update" your data using your new changes in migration. Instead of this, Seed only initialize you data by defined strategy. So, I don't know strategy that can initialize your current model by data from older model

Comment: The safe way is to create a second db, and move afterwords data from old db to the new db. Takes more time but its safer. Than change the connection string in your app to use new database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you follow these steps:

1. create temporary tables that represent the data & relationships of the affected tables. Ensure you do this outside of EF, using `CREATE TABLE` sql
2. **BEFORE** running `Update-Database`, run a script to move data from the tables in question to your temp tables
3. Run `Update-Database`
4. Run script to insert data and relationships back into your new tables
5. Drop temp tables

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. I think that EF should provide support for these cases and so do everything in C #. Finally, it's remain as part of the project migrations.